# What is the mistake in this: $1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-...=0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I needed to find the value of $1 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} -\frac{1}{4}$ ... and came up with this. Let:

$$1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} +... = x$$

$$(1 + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} +...) + \frac{1}{2}(1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} +...)= x$$

$$1 + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} + ... =\frac{x}{2}$$

Now:

$$1 -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4}...= (1+ \frac{1}{3} +\frac{1}{5} +...)-\frac{1}{2}(1+ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} +\frac{1}{4} +...)
=\frac{x}{2} - \frac{1}{2}x =0$$

which is clearly wrong since the expected answer was ln2. I am unable to see what I have done wrong here.

Comment: The series is divergent

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The mistake happens on this line:

> Let $1 + \frac12 + \frac13 + \frac14 + \frac15 +... = x$

the mistake is assuming that there exists some $x\in\mathbb R$ for which the above equation is true. Such an $x$ does not exist, because the series is divergent (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Divergence) for at least two ways of proving this).

Since the line highlighted above is false, everything that follows this line is unfounded, as it is proving statements from a false assumption (and thus trivially possible; everything follows from a false statement).

Answer (score 3):

Infinity is not a well-defined number: if infinity were a number, it would contradict with the existing principles of mathematics.

Therefore this line:

> Let $1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + 1/5 + \cdots = x$

does not make sense if $x$ is assumed to be a finite number.

Answer (score 3):

The others have correctly pointed out the first error in trying to assign $x$ to a divergent series, but there's another, arguably more important, error made later when you write

> 1 -1/2 + 1/3 - 1/4...= (1+ 1/3 +1/5 +...)-1/2(1+ 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 +...)

This is wrong, as the series on the left is only **conditionally** convergent, so we cannot re-arrange the terms as you've done on the right-hand side.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake starts from yous first assumption, which is

$1 + \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4} +\frac{1}{5}... = x$

This is because we know that $x$ is not exist as it is a divergent series.
So we cannot simply assume something doesn't exist to be a value of it.
Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out by the other answers, the problem in your reasoning is that you used the [Harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) as if it converged to a finite value.

However, there are more caveats:

The series
$$\frac11-\frac12+\frac13-\frac14\pm\cdots$$
converges only [conditionally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_convergence), but not absolutely.  This means you can reorder the series in such a way that it converges to any real number you like, same for +∞ and −∞. See [Riemann's rearrangement theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem).

For example, to reorder it in such a way that it converges to π, do the following:

1. Add remaining, positive elements with the smallest (by absolute value) denominators and goto 2. once the partial sum is ≥ π.
2. Add remaining, negative elements with the smallest (by absolute value) denominators and goto 1. once the partial sum is ≤ π.
3. and 2. can always be achieved by adding finitely many elements only because the Harmonic series diverges to ∞.  You can replace π by any real number and it still works the same way.